# Android 8 native crash at native library

Tags: android, native

Since the rollout of Android 8 Oreo, our app has been consistently crashing in different places. All the play store crash reports show native crashes. The most frequently occuring one seems to be at native library.

The most frequent device that crashes is the Google Pixel and Pixel XL have also shown a few.

I ll post the crash log below. I m struggling to find what causes the crash.

Any help is appreciated.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/sailfish/sailfish:8.0.0/OPR6.170623.012/4283428:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 9857, tid: 9857, name: stampphoto  >>> com.******.***** <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
Cause: null pointer dereference
    r0 ea26cec8  r1 00000001  r2 0000007f  r3 00000002
    r4 000030ca  r5 00000000  r6 ff7ed650  r7 ff7ed628
    r8 13b40240  r9 00000043  sl ea26b470  fp ff7ed664
    ip ea0985d1  sp ff7ed5a8  lr ea168b15  pc ea168b1e  cpsr 600b0030
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00332b1e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art35InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgsERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+89)
    #01 pc 00262785  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI17CallObjectMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+436)
    #02 pc 0006398b  /data/app/com.a.a-h8bA8DmI-3kJ2bP4GkGvoA==/base.apk (offset 0x3c4000)
    #03 pc 0006468b  /data/app/com.a.a-h8bA8DmI-3kJ2bP4GkGvoA==/base.apk (offset 0x3c4000)
    #04 pc 0006fddf  /data/app/com.a.a-h8bA8DmI-3kJ2bP4GkGvoA==/oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x45000)
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you solved this issue, if so can you please share the solution ?

Comment: I also facing this issue, can you solve it or not?

Comment: I am still facing this issue. didn't get any proper solution.